# Swing monitor unsaved changes

Tags: java, swing

I have developed a graphical interface consisting of 12 **JPanels**, each containing 4 to 10 **JTextFields.**
I want to implement an **unsaved-changes-warning** in case the user has altered the content of some JTextFields, but did not commit the changes to the **database.**

How to achieve this ?
My first idea was to use **ItemListener** and register all JTextFields. I could store a variable **boolean unsavedChanges** for each panel and check whether all panels are false.

Can you imagine another maybe more efficient solution ?

Comment: You could use a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead and add it to the result of [JTextField.getDocument()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

1. You could register a DocumentListener on the document of every JTextField.

   `textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener)`

   The disadvantage: text fields are marked as changed even if the user has changed the value to the original value. To handle this problem you could save the original value in your own document listener and compare new values to it. The method hasChanged() gives you the wanted information.

   ```
   import javax.swing.event.*;
   import javax.swing.text.*;

   public class DocumentChangeListener implements DocumentListener {

       private boolean changed;
       private final String originalValue;

       public DocumentChangeListener(String originalValue) {
           this.originalValue = originalValue;
       }

       protected void changed(DocumentEvent e) {
           if (e.getDocument() instanceof PlainDocument) {
               PlainDocument doc = ((PlainDocument)e.getDocument());
               try {
                   String value = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
                   changed = originalValue == null || !originalValue.equals(value);
               } catch(BadLocationException exc) {
                   exc.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }

       public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           changed(e);
       }

       public boolean hasChanged() {
           return this.changed;
       }

       public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           changed(e);
       }

       public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
           changed(e);
       }
   }
   ```
2. You could save the original values displayed in the text fields as you get them from the database in a map or something like this. When you check the panels you have to compare the content of the text fields with the original values.

**EDIT**

To collect the change information of every text field you can use a class like this. You create one instance of it in your frame and pass it to all panels.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ChangeManager {

    private final Collection<DocumentChangeListener> listeners;

    public ChangeManager() {
        listeners = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public boolean hasChanged() {
        for(DocumentChangeListener listener : listeners) {
            if(listener.hasChanged()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void register(JTextComponent textComponent, String originalValue) {
        DocumentChangeListener listener = new DocumentChangeListener(
                originalValue);
        textComponent.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I am still not sure how to pass the changed information through a stack of Jpanels up to the MainClass JFrame.